# .net tcp packet without ip header

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, tcp

Is there a way in .net to send a tcp packet without including the ip header?
I have a small hardware device that does tcp/ip communication, except for 1 command that requires the ip header to be removed. 
I found this question on stackoverflow: [why can't I send this packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549163/why-cant-i-send-this-ip-packet).
I tried something similar, with a small change like:

```
rawSocket.SetSocketOption( socketLevel, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, 0 );
```

but, as expected from the reply on this question, it didn't work (apparently it's not possible to use raw sockets on newer windows machines).
Is there any other way that this could be achieved?
Thanks.